# Proper maps between pairs

Tags: general-topology, definition

If $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ are pairs of topological spaces, what would be a good notion of a **proper** map $f: (X,A) \to (Y,B)$?

Maybe $f:X\to Y$ is proper and $f|_A: A\to B$ is proper?

Answer (score 0):

In topology, a proper map f:X -> Y is a map with
for all U compact subset Y, $f^{-1}(U)$ is compact.

As A is not a subset of X, it makes no sense to
restrict f to A.  What notion of proper are you
using?  Something like proper subset?

Comment: A pair $(X,A)$ is a topological space $X$ and $A\subset X$. A map $f: (X,A) \to (Y,B)$ is a map $f:X\to Y$ such that $f(A)\subset B$.

Comment: The notation (X,A) for a topological space means that X is the space, ie the set of points, and A subset P(X), is the topology.   Correcting for that A subset X mistake and accomodating the abuse of notation, f is called an open map.

Comment: Usually a **pair of spaces** is what I said in my comment above.  $A$ could be a topology and $(X,A)$ would then denote a topological space, but I mentioned in my question that $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ were *pair* of spaces.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_pair

Comment: @KlausNiederkrüger.  I'd guess a  map f:X -> Y, g:A -> B, from (X,A) to (Y,B) would be proper when f and g are proper. For example, f is proper and A compact.